# Does python's csv.reader read the entire file into memory?

Tags: python, csv

Does the csvreader object read the entire file into memory? If I have big data, would it crash because of low memory. Or it's only a pointer so that I can process each line?

```
import csv
with open('RawData.csv','r') as file:
    csvreader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csvreader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: The actual reading happens in the loop.

Comment: It is only a pointer it will not load the whole file in the memory. However, it actually depends on the way you are opening the file. .read() loads the complete file in the ram.

Answer (score 10):

From the [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) documentation:

> Return a reader object which will iterate over lines in the given
>   csvfile. csvfile can be any object which supports the iterator
>   protocol and returns a string each time its `__next__()` method is
>   called — **file objects and list objects are both suitable.**

(Emphasis mine.)

What you have is a *wrapper* around the file object. The file pointer does all the dirty work of *efficiently* iterating over the lines of your file, and the csv module's Reader parses those lines as they're read in.

So yes, +1 for memory friendliness and efficiency.

Comment: I am not seeing this behavior. When I iterate over rows in a 2.5GB .csv file with `csv.DictReader`, I see the `RES` memory of the Python process grow to 2.5GB before the script finishes. Perhaps this memory efficiency was the intended effect but it does not seem to be playing out correctly in real life.

Comment: Not sure, but it may be that csv reader shoul be wrapped in a function that yields file lines instead of just returning them. This wrapper will act as a generator which iterates over file line by line, not loading it to the RAM. Try this code:

def read_file_data(path):
    with open(path, newline='') as file_data:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file_data)
        for line in reader:
            yield line
...

for row in read_file_data('report.csv'): pass

Comment: Search for "Simple CSV Data Wrangling with Python" article in Internet for further explanations.